# cURL Call to undefined function curl_init

Tags: php, curl, debian

I've got a problem with my website and server (DEBIAN 8).

I've got an error:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/example.pl/public_html/ajax.php

I checked that I have got curl and yes:

```
root@Debian-84-jessie-64-minimal ~ # apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Show `ajax.php` code

Comment: Need top enable curl via php.ini

Comment: Is php5-curl installed? (`apt-get install php5-curl`)

Answer (score 0):

> Go to your php.ini file and remove the ; mark from the beginning of
>   the following line:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Then it will look like this :-

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl might be installed but you still need to enable the curl extension for php.

Go to your php.ini file and uncomment:  'extension=php_curl.dll'

Answer (score 0):

you need open  php extension module named 'curl'